# Apply scale on all keyframes

Tags: animation, keyframes

I want to scale down an animated model and apply scale.
The problem is that when applying the scale to the armature, the keyframes remain unchanged, so their location/scale is incorrect.

Is there a way to apply scale on all keyframes?
Especially to correct their location.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the scale function in the Graph editor the same way as in the 3D viewer. make sure that all the objects with keyframes you want to adjust are loaded in the Graph editor and visible, then use <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, then <kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd> and the amount you want to scale by (i.e. <kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>-</kbd>,<kbd>5</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>1</kbd>,<kbd>.</kbd>,<kbd>2</kbd>,<kbd>5</kbd>, etc. and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Scaling along X-axis will change the timing (speed) of the animation. If you want to change the VALUES, scale along the Y-axis.

Comment: This also scales rotations, which is _not_ what you want.